# When I start My SAP MMC EC6 server one service is not getting to wait mode

Tags: abap, sap-basis

[image: When EC6 server is started, below selected service is not getting into wait mode.]

Can someone of you help me, how to make the following service selected in the image get into wait mode after starting the server.
Please let me know if developer trace is required to be posted for resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that particular process is a `BATCH` process, a process that runs scheduled background tasks (maintained by transaction `SM36`/`SM37`). If the process is busy right after starting the server, that means there were scheduled tasks with status `released` waiting for execution, and as soon as the server was up, it started those tasks.

If you want to make sure the system doesn't immediately start released background tasks, you'll have to set the status back to scheduled (which, thanks to a bit of weird translation, means they won't be executed because they are not released).

if you want to start the server without having a chance to first change the job status in `SM37`, you would either have to reset the status on database level (likely not officially supported by SAP) or first start the server without any `BATCH` processes (which would give you a number of great big warning messages upon login) and change the job status before then restarting the server with the `BATCH` processes. You can set the number of processes for each type in the profile of your instance (parameter `rdisp/wp_no_btc`).